# SearchPlus Plugin Not Syncing Indexes

Tags: search, plugin-searchplus

For the past couple of months now, I've noticed on my websites using the SearchPlus plugin that indexes are no longer syncing with Algolia. This also means that creating new search indexes is not possible.

I've been updating indexes manually via the Algolia dashboard, but this means that I can't create new indexes at all.

My best guess is that the plugin is no longer compatible with Algolia's API. Has anyone encountered this, or come up with a fix for this issue?

Comment: The plugin developer is unresponsive via their website and social channels, so figuring it out is a necessity. It's a pity, because it's such a useful plugin. Using Algolia's instansearch.js is just not as easy to work with.

Comment: Any update on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Algolia changed their index quotas, requiring records to be no larger than 10kb for the Community Edition plan.

My issue was solved by upgrading my to the Essential plan, and creating a custom mapping with the Search Plus plugin, to make sure I kept the record size only as large as it needed to be.

I was experiencing issues particularly with Commerce products that had variants and other custom fields.

Comment: The guys at [Top Shelf Craft](http://www.topshelfcraft.com) gave me a few pointers on how to implement a custom mapping by extending the Search Plus plugin. I've linked my solution [here](https://github.com/kojint/spcustommap).

Answer (score 1):

As the first answer states, the reason why this is happening is Algolia changed the maximum record size on the free plan. When syncing the index, at some point you are likely getting a 400 error from a specific entry causing the index sync to stop.

You can upgrade to essential to essentially get an increased record size threshold. However from the code side, you can implement a few measures to help avoid this error altogether.

- Truncate the returned output for fields that are typically large, so when Algolia maps it, it takes a limited value.
- Chunk/split larger records into parts.

https://discourse.algolia.com/t/spliting-long-text-to-records/3832/4